# How to effectively use particle emitters on an animated mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, geometry-nodes, particles, collision

When baking my particle simulation to the animated mesh, it only emits the particles from the first frame of the animation and continues to emit from that point, while the mesh continues its animation. Is there a way to have the particle system emit from the mesh (and possibly collide with the mesh) throughout the duration of the animation, specifically from the mesh?

I have tried rearranging the order of my modifiers, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Alternatively, if this could be better achieved with geo nodes, advice/guidance on that area would be appreciated as well.